# nested defines in makefile

Tags: makefile, variable-expansion

I'm very new to creating makefiles, so this question might be trivial. If I'm using bad coding practices, I would appreciate to be pointed at it.

I am trying to create a generic makefile that creates rules based on input variables. At the end of my posting is a "minimal" example.

I got 2 problems.

1. In line 35 I instantiate the meta_template. I would expect the variable $(Dirs) to be expanded and then the meta_template to be called with each entry of $(Dirs). But it only expands till the second last, ie. the result of make terminates with:

   `make: *** No rule to make target 'Dir03Target01Tag01', needed by 'Dir03'.  Stop.`
2. In line 21 I want to create a shortcut rule, a rule that prerequisites all tags to a given example.
   Eg: `Dir01Target02: Dir01Target02Tag04 Dir01Target02Tag05`

   First I was puzzled that I couldn't use `$($$(1)Tags)` but had to use `$$($$(1)Tags)` to access the according Tags. (stored in Target01Tags for example).

   Using `$(addprefix)` does not seem to expand as I expected, ie the result of `make Dir01Target01` is:

   `Create Rule Dir01Target01 with Dir01Target01Tag01 Tag02 Tag03`

   where I expected it to be:

   `Create Rule Dir01Target01 with Dir01Target01Tag01 Dir01Target01Tag02 Dir01Target01Tag03`

**edit:** I found the answer to question 2. I had `$(addprefix $(1)$$(1),$$($$(1)Tags))`alter to `$$(addprefix $(1)$$(1),$$($$(1)Tags))`. I think it's because this needs to be expanded in 2 runs. So after the first run `$(addprefix Dirxx$(1),$($(1)Tags))` remains.

Thanks in advance.

```
# Targets to compile
Targets = Target01 Target02

# Tags to add to Targets
Target01Tags = Tag01 Tag02 Tag03
Target02Tags = Tag04 Tag05

# Some List (in the actual makefile a list of directories $(wildcard NumeratedDir*))
Dirs = Dir01 Dir02 Dir03

all: $(Dirs)

define meta_template
$(1): $(foreach target,$(Targets),$(foreach tag,$($(target)Tags),$(1)$(target)$(tag)))

define compile_meta
# $(1) 1st argument of meta_compile (<Dirs>xx, eg Dir03)
# $$(1) 1st argument of compile_template (<Targets>, eg Target01)

$(1)$$(1): #$(addprefix $(1)$$(1),$($$(1)Tags))
    @echo Create Rule $(1)$$(1) with $(addprefix $(1)$$(1),$$($$(1)Tags))  <---- Line21
endef
$(foreach target,$(Targets),$(eval $(call compile_meta,$(target))))

define compile_template
# $(1) 1st argument of meta_compile (<Dirs>xx, eg Dir03)
# $$(1) 1st argument of compile_template (<Targets>, eg Target01)
# $$(2) 2nd argument of compile_template (<Targets>Tags, eg Tag01)

# create rule using arguments (eg Dir03Target01Tag01)
$(1)$$(1)$$(2):
    @echo Create Rule $(1)$$(1)$$(2)

endef
$(foreach target,$(Targets),$(foreach tag,$($(target)Tags),$(eval $(call compile_template,$(target),$(tag))))) <--- Line35

endef
$(foreach prog,$(Dirs),$(eval $(call meta_template,$(prog))))
```

Comment: You're new to makefiles? I'm pretty experienced with them, and I find this one dizzying. You seem to be trying to implement a build system interpreter in Make. This can be done as an exercise in hacking for its own sake, but please don't try to use it as a real-world build system.

Comment: @Beta I looked into me manual on sunday for the first time, so pretty new, yes. I agree that using an interpreted language like python would be a better choice. I work at a university and we use makefiles to compile the LaTeX sources for our lectures. We provide tags when compiling so we get multiple version, for example for Homework.tex there we might want a version with just the tasks, a version with soultions, and a version with additional correcting instructions.
As every course has different build targets and tags, I wanted the makefile to be as genereic as possible.